# d3js world map with geoJSon

Tags: javascript, graph, dictionary, d3.js, geojson

Is there any link which points to an chart/graph/map example using D3JS with World geoJSON data and highlights some of the location based on certain data with lat/lng?

For example, the world map should be rendered using **world-geo.json** and then adding/highlighting few countries based on another dataset **web-user-statistics.json**

Thanks
Thangaraju R

Comment: This is not related to the question. The question is about D3.js and geoJSON, but your link refers to "How To Show DropDownList in JQGRID ASP.Net MVC Razor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.larsko.org/v/igdp/) is an example that in addition to showing a world map allows to select particular countries which will be highlighted and zoomed into. [This example](http://www.larsko.org/v/cac/) doesn't show a map of the entire globe, but is probably closer to what you're looking for as it shows data for each country (both by colour and on mouse over). It also uses two different JSON files for the different data.

Comment: Thanks Lars. By Merging these two examples, I could make out, what I need. Thanks